# Hermitian operator's eigenvectors are not orthonormal and not complete

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

I am dealing with the following operator:
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -3i \\
        0 & 3i & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix is Hermitian.
I need to find eigenvectors, check that they are orthonormal and complete.

I got these eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

for v1=2,

b1= \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        (3/2) iy \\
        \end{pmatrix}

for v1=3,

b2= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        y \\
        iy \\
        \end{pmatrix}

for v1=-3,

b3= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        y \\
        -iy \\
        \end{pmatrix}

However they are neither orthonormal nor complete and it seems impossible to find appropriate coefficients.

I have spent 2 days on this task. So far, no solution has been found. This is the only exercise I have not managed to solve, so, I guess, the algorithms I use are correct.

Comment: One eigenvector is $(1,0,0)^T$. The others can be found by looking at the $2 \times 2$ submatrix.

Comment: Regarding eigenvalues, I checked mine using Mathcad.

Comment: I don't see where you're getting your answer for $\lambda=2$. The RREF of $B-\lambda I$ is $\left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$, whose nullspace consists of all vectors of the form $\left[\begin{matrix}x\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$.

Comment: Also: The eigenvectors are already orthogonal. All you have to do is to normalize them.

Comment: If the first eigenvector looks like that, than everything is OK! However, the first characteristic equation 0*x+0*y+0*z=0 and in others we multiply x by 0, so, it must be independent, I guess.

Comment: ye, I get it. We can assume x of the vector to be 1 and y to be 0. Thanks! It worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $\lambda=2$, $a=(1,0,0)$

for $\lambda=-3$, $b=(0,i,1)$

for $\lambda=3$, $c=(0,-i,1)$

Note that
$\color{red}{\langle U,V\rangle=U\bar V^T}$ so $\langle c,b\rangle=c\bar b^T=0.0+i.i+1.1=-1+1=0$...

(I think your pro was in definition of inner product)

Comment: May I ask how you get the first eigenvector?

Comment: ye, I get it. We can assume x of the vector to be 1 and y to be 0. Thanks! It worked!!